# Why are the majority of characters named after car manufacturers?

Tags: hitsugi-no-chaika

Most of the character's last name comes from a car manufacturer. Acura is a luxury car manufacturer under Honda. Gaz is a Russian car manufacturer. There are others like this such as Trabant, Lancia, Arbath, Dodge, Calloway, etc.

Has the author given his reason for this naming convention?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sakaki Ichiro (aka the author) used a distinctive naming scheme in his other work *Scrapped Princess* as well, but there the characters were named after firearms / guns instead ([its wiki page even has a section about that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrapped_Princess#Names_and_firearm_references)).

So it may very well just be that he likes to have his character names be a reference to something. :)